# How do I seperate an array of numbers with a blank space between them?

Tags: javascript

Let's say my array is:

```
const array = [20, 30, 21, 15, 80];
```

If I want to for example console.log it, it will show the following:

```
20,30,21,15,80
```

But I want the output to be

```
20 30 21 15 80
```

in the console.log.

How do I make it seperate using a blank space? I tried using .split and other stuff and it didn't work. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 5):

You could use `.join()`

```js
const array = [20, 30, 21, 15, 80];

console.log(array.join(' '))
```

---

**Reference**

[Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 1):

To show the actual numbers (rather than strings), you can spread the numbers from `array` into the call to `console.log`. As console.log can take multiple arguments it will print each on the same line:

```js
const array = [20, 30, 21, 15, 80];
console.log(...array);
```